# Divisible By 2,3,4,7

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the least positive number that is divisible by 2 if after added 2, divisible by 3 after added 3, divisible by 4 after added 4 and divisible by 7 after added 7.

Comment: Note:  numbers that are divisible by $2$ if added $2$ were already divisible by $2$.  And so on.

Comment: So: what is the least positive number that is divisible by $2,3,4,$ and $7$?

Comment: Also every number which is divisible by 4, is divisible by 2.

Comment: what about 3 and 7?

Comment: I think maybe it is just a trick question or whatever, and +those numbers indicate that the number$\ge$7.

Answer (score 0):

See that the smaller number that is divisible by 2, 3, 4 and 7 is:
2^2•3•7
Then, all of these numbers can be writed like you want to add, for example:
2^2•3•7 = 7•k
Then 7•k+7 = 7(k+1) and it's divisible by 7.

Comment: Sir, Can you please give us an explanation because we are newbies in mathematics.

Comment: Sure. First of all we define prime numbers that have only two divisors, 1 and itself. For example, 2. Then, exists a theorem that I won't prove now, but trust in it, that say that every number not prime, so composite, can be writed   by prime factors. For example, 14 can be writed as 7•2, where 7 and 2 are prime numbers. Also, only exists one combination of numbers to write one. Finally, we define de LCM of n numbers  as the smaller number thaf is divisible by n1, n2, n3,..., n. To calculate it, we use the descompotition and multiply all not repeated (if not, we are considering a divisor x2)

Comment: To do it in the exercise, we have to calculate the LCM by (2,3,4,7). First of all, we note that every number are prime except 4. So we have to descomposite it in primes. 4 = 2•2 = 2^2. Then we have to multiply all numbers. If one is repeated (in this case 2, we have to consider only the 2 with big exponent, in this case 2^2). So the smaller number divisible by 2,3,4,7 = 2^2•3•7 = 84. Then, look if u add 2,3,4 or 7, by factorization, it will be still divisible by all lf they. If you still understand a step, just say it here.

Answer (score 0):

$N1=84$

$N1+2=86$ is divisible by 2

$N1+3=87$ is divisible by 3

$N1+4=88$ is divisible by 4

$N1+7=91$ is divisible by 7

$N2=168$

$N2+2=170$ is divisible by 2

$N2+3=171$ is divisible by 3

$N2+4=172$ is divisible by 4

$N2+7=175$ is divisible by 7